# Flot bar chart: bars overlapping on time axis issue

Tags: jquery, time, flot, bar-chart, overlapping

I am trying to plot expense data against time axis, and I see the data bars are overlapping if they are showing data for the same date. I was expecting the graph to show the bars asjascent to each other but that is not the case. See a [sample of code at this link](http://jsfiddle.net/vpfaiz/A8yNV/)...

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), newJson, 
{
    bars: {
        show: 1,
        barWidth: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 10
    },
    xaxis: { mode:"time" }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, that isn't possible in flot without using some sort of plugin.  I suggest you either use the [stacking plugin](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/stacking/index.html) to get a vertical stack, or an external plugin like [orderBars](http://en.benjaminbuffet.com/labs/flot/).

In each of them, you add an option to each series specifying that it should be stacked/ordered.  Or to the overall series options for bars if you want it to apply for everything.

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), newJson, 
    {bars: { order:1, show: 1, barWidth: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 10 },
     xaxis: { mode:"time" }
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/A8yNV/7/

Comment: Thanks... I have some other issues now though this OrderBars seems to fix some.. :)

Comment: It may be a good idea to implement a plugin that does not change the x values of bars...

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved an issue with the ORDER property : it does not work if one of the serie has a NULL value.
Indeed, I was using NULL value to avoid a get a tiny (0) line for the serie, but in this case the following order of the stacks are completely disturb.
By setting a 0 (ZERO) instead of NULL : all is okay.

Note : the same problem with or without the "orderBars plugin".

Hope this will help.