# Flot Bar Chart - how to create non stack up values

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, flot

I'm new to flot. I have this bar chart:
[image]

and here is the code I used for it:

```
$.getJSON('chartBar.json', function(graphDataBar){

    $.plot($('#graph-bars'), graphDataBar, {
        series: {
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: .1,
                align: 'right'


            },
            shadowSize: 0
        },
        grid: {
            color: '#646464',
            borderColor: 'transparent',
            borderWidth: 20,
            hoverable: true
        },
        xaxis: {
            tickColor: 'transparent',
            ticks: [[6,'Week 48'],[7,'Week 49'],[8,'Week 50'],[9,'Week 51'],[10,'Week 52']],
            min: 5.5,
            max: 10.5,
            mode: 'time',
         timeformat: "%b %d",
         minTickSize: [1, "day"],
         tickSize: [1, "day"],
         autoscaleMargin: .10
        },
        yaxis: {
            tickSize: 5
        }
    });
```

I ve tried to use the properties inside x-axis but nothing seems to help.
I know there is a way to do it, I ve seen examples such as [This](http://www.pikemere.co.uk/blog/tutorial-flot-how-to-create-bar-charts-updated/) one.
But it doesnt seem to work.
What Im trying to succeed here is this
[image]

As well I ve seen other sample on Stackoverflow like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264954/flot-bar-chart-bars-overlapping-on-time-axis-issue)
But it still didnt work out. Im not sure if I see this the wrong way, or if I need to use the timestamp in order to make it work, but I do it the wrong way.

Could anyone explain to me how the solution would work? I would like to understand it for future Bar Charts

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need a side-by-side plugin like this: https://github.com/pkoltermann/SideBySideImproved

Comment: Any chance you post your data (the chartBar.json file)?

Answer (score 0):

I've made an assumption that the JSON data is the same as in your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796270/flot-wont-upload-json) so apologies if this is not the case.

I've created a Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9x7aJ/4977/) that demonstrates the "non stacked bars" using the following JSON data:

```
[
    {       
        "data": [ [6, 520], [7, 600], [8, 850], [9, 900], [10, 300] ],
        "color": "#F02626",
        "points": {  "fillColor": "#F02626", "radius": 6 },
        "lines": { "fillColor": "#CCF8FF"}
    }, 
    {
        "data": [ [6, 300], [7, 400], [8, 550], [9, 750], [10, 200] ],
        "color": "#26F041",
        "points": { "radius": 10, "fillColor": "#26F041" }
    }, 
    {
        "data": [ [6, 200], [7, 150], [8, 380], [9, 400], [10, 100] ],
        "color": "#20AEFA",
        "points": { "radius": 6, "fillColor": "#20AEFA"}
    }
]
```

This uses the [orderBars plugin](http://en.benjaminbuffet.com/flot/). The key to getting the bars to appear side by side (rather than vertically) is to set the `series.bars.order` attribute to 1:

```
series: {
    bars: {
        ...
        order: 1
    }
},
```